# Difference between goto and a while loop with system performance

Tags: c, performance, crash, performance-testing

When I use an infinite loop with `while` which just prints `Hello, World`, my computer freeze. But when I use `goto` and a label which also makes an infinite loop, everything is fine. Why does using `while` cause my computer to crash but using `goto` does not? Why `while` loading more on the computer?

```c
#include <stdio.h> // IO

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    call:
        printf("Hello World!");

    goto call;
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h> // IO

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    while (1) { printf("Hello World!"); }

    return 0;
}
```

***compare files line by line:***

```
$ gcc -S while.c goto.c
$ ls
goto.c  goto.s  while.c  while.s
$ diff while.s goto.s
1c1
<   .file   "goto.c"
---
>   .file   "while.c"
```

Comment: Please define your `freeze` and `crash`.

Comment: Could you please invoke next comands?
1. ```gcc -S``` for both versions
You will get files with .s extension
2.``` diff goto.s while.s```
And show to us.

For example on my machine was generated absolutely the same assembler. And on my machine both programs works with the same loading.

Comment: @terehpp I have updated

Comment: @VladFeinstein My computer freezes and then I have to force turn it off by holding the power-on button for like 10 sec

Comment: So as you can see you have the same assembler for both files.
My opinion. That it's just random event that one version of program load harder the cpu.
Maybe some magic happens in linker... But for me both programs are the same, and they should work the same.

Comment: @terehpp okay, thank you. It depends on a lot of things so we can't really answer my question. Thank you anyway

Comment: Instead of power down, did you try `Ctrl+C`? Your code would load ONE CPU core 100%, but nobody has only one core now.

Comment: Yeah....what OS are you running it under?

Comment: @VladFeinstein that would only work on Linux, maybe MacOS . The Windows way to suffer and reboot .

Comment: @APJo totally incorrect since Windows 3.1:((  The Task Manager can easily shut down looping processes.

Comment: @MartinJames Ah, *if* you can get Task Manager to launch , lol

Comment: @APJo you can, on all Windows since 3.1, easily, even with many looping processes: the TM has an above-normal priority.  Why are you spreading this FUD?

Comment: @MartinJames Ah, I am not spreading anything, I simply have had it happen very often to me that when windows froze, so did TM ... maybe its just my luck , and of course you may very well be right, I speak from experience (which lead me to deduce that OP may not have been ablt to get TM to do his bidding) not deep knowledge of the Windows system :)

Comment: @APJo I don't have deep knowledge of the Winddows system either, (it's closed-source and I do not work for MS or a trusted partner), but I do have a lot of experience.  Since NT/W2k, I have never had to reboot Windows because of a looping process/thread.